# Why are tsplot and ADF test results inconsistent?

Tags: time-series, stationarity, seasonality, augmented-dickey-fuller

I have airline time series. Here is the tsplot

[image]

The data clearly seems non-stationary to me. However, ADF test produces a p value of 0.01, indicating that the data is stationary. Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $H_0$ of the ADF test is presence of a unit root. A low $p$-value suggests you should reject $H_0$ (thus no unit root). This is perfectly compatible with the graph. The data has a smooth time trend and very pronounced seasonality, but clearly *not* a unit root.

Comment: What about this output? It indicates that the alternative hypothesis is stationary. Since p=0.01, H0 is rejected. Am I missing something?

Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test

data:  tsdata
Dickey-Fuller = -6.8654, Lag order = 5, p-value = 0.01
alternative hypothesis: stationary

Warning message:
In adf.test(tsdata) : p-value smaller than printed p-value
>

Comment: @Günal, the output is a bit misleading. The model underlying the test assumes the time series is either stationary or has a unit root. However, in reality there are many series that do not fall in either category, i.e. they are nonstationary yet do not have a unit root. Your case seems to be an example of that.